# Google Gdata ContactService Oauth2 Java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gdata, google-shared-contacts

**EDIT:**
The solution to my problem shows... well, NEVER try to work with copy & paste code without thinking!

**SOLUTION**

To be able to change my Service, the Service should NEVER be FINAL. Removing final enabled *setCredentials(credential)* and let me reach my contacts.

Correct ContactsService init:

```
/**
 * Service used to communicate with contacts feed.
 */
private ContactsService service = new ContactsService(APPLICATION_NAME);
```

after this, no errors remained ;)

**Original Question**

I'm trying to build a GWT-Server-Side call to **Google GData Contacts API V3.0**. 
I'm using GWT 2.5.1 and jre6. For this I want to implement the API for **native application**. Not as a web-server-service.

I do receive *ACCESS_TOKEN* and *REFRESH_TOKEN*.

I want to be able, to read/update/delete contacts and synchronize them with my database.

Although I found several questions, no solution or problem was directed at the native application approach.

Thanks for everybody trying to help!

**My Problem**

```
ContactFeed resultFeed = service.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
```

only results in ERROR:

```
15:12:41,513 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information
15:12:41,514 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.initFromAuthHeader(AuthenticationException.java:96)
```

.....

**My question**

Did anybody else receive those problems?

Can I use `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential` to authorize the `ContactsService`?

Is there a way to create this Header myself as a workaround?

My Code including imports:

**ContactSerice Initialization**

```
private final ContactsService service = new ContactsService(APPLICATION_NAME);
```

**ImportFunction**

```
@Override
public Integer importGoogleContactData() 
{
    int numberOfImportedContacts = 0;
    System.out.println( "INFO GDataServiceImpl reached importGoogleContactData()");
    try 
    {
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);

        //authorization
        Credential credential = authorize();
        credential.refreshToken();

        System.out.println( "INFO credential = getAccessToken() " + credential.getAccessToken() );
        System.out.println( "INFO credential = getRefreshToken() " + credential.getRefreshToken() );

        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
        service.useSsl();
        System.out.println( "INFO service = getServiceVersion() " + service.getServiceVersion() );

        feedUrl = new URL( "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full" );
        System.out.println("INFO url: " + feedUrl.toString() );

        ContactFeed resultFeed = service.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
        // Print the results
        System.out.println(resultFeed.getTitle().getPlainText());
        for (ContactEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries())
        {
            numberOfImportedContacts++;
            System.out.println("INFO found Contact: " + entry.getName() );
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (Throwable t) 
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return numberOfImportedContacts;
}
```

**authorize()**

```
/** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception 
{
    String systemEncoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("../server/default/conf/client_secret_<CLIENT_ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com.json");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader( fileInputStream , systemEncoding);
    clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load( JSON_FACTORY, inputStreamReader );

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory).build();

    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
  }
```

**Complete imports**

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2;
import com.google.api.services.oauth2.model.Userinfoplus;
import com.google.gdata.client.contacts.ContactsService;
import com.google.gdata.data.contacts.ContactEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.contacts.ContactFeed;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
```

**Complete Server output:**

```
2014-03-05 15:37:53,759 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) INFO GDataServiceImpl reached importGoogleContactData()

2014-03-05 15:37:53,798 WARNING [com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\evergrin\.store\oauth2
2014-03-05 15:37:53,799 WARNING [com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\evergrin\.store\oauth2
2014-03-05 15:37:54,333 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) INFO credential = getAccessToken() <ACCESS_TOKEN>
2014-03-05 15:37:54,334 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) INFO credential = getRefreshToken() <REFRESH_TOKEN>
2014-03-05 15:37:54,336 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) INFO service = getServiceVersion() GContacts-Java/3.1.0 GData-Java/1.47.1(gzip)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,336 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) INFO url: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full
2014-03-05 15:37:54,476 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information
2014-03-05 15:37:54,477 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.initFromAuthHeader(AuthenticationException.java:96)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,486 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.<init>(AuthenticationException.java:67)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,487 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:608)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,487 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,487 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,487 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,487 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,488 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,488 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,488 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,488 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,488 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at sung.app.dieligen.dropkick.gwt.server.gdata.GDataServiceImpl.importGoogleContactData(GDataServiceImpl.java:185)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,488 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,489 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,489 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,489 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,489 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,489 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,490 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,490 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,490 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,490 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,490 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,490 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,491 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,491 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,491 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,491 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,492 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,492 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,492 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,492 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,492 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,493 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,493 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,493 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,493 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,493 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,493 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
2014-03-05 15:37:54,494 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```